# Chart.js - legend position covered by chart itself - how to adjust?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

**Problem**: The chart legend covers top of the chart.

**What I have done**: I read the docs for chart js but cannot find a property to lift the legend up over the chart itself. Also, changing the size of the chart (canvas) does not work as it changes the whole thing altogether.

**Semi-solutions**: I understand there is an option to put the legend in the bottom and left and right, but I would like to keep it on top.

[image]
Any ideas how to change it, please?

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "some data",
      fontColor: "#999",
      fontStyle: "300",
      fontSize: 12,
      fontFamily: '"Poppins", sans-serif'
    },
    legend: {
      padding: 20
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: "index",
      intersect: true
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit:** It is a known bug that appeared in version 2.7 and till now March 2017 has not got a solution. One thing to help it is to use not 10th increments in data. (The bug is something to do with rounding)

Comment: Could you provide code sample?:

Comment: Added code sample.

Comment: It is a bug. Developers are aware. More on it -https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4202